# ByteBuffer isn't filled with correct data

Tags: java, arrays, sockets, nio, bytebuffer

recently I switched from multithreaded sockets to NIO sockets.
Unfortunately I'm struggling with converting raw packet data to the ByteBuffer (or something similiar to it)

Well here you have two outputs, one of the resulting packet and the resulting ByteBuffer content that should be sent.

```
SEND [0xfa2] 00 00 00 00 A2 0F 02 00 FE FF // the packet that should be sent
SEND [0xfa2] 00 00 00 00 A2 0F 02 00 00 00 // ByteBuffer content that is sent
```

As you can see, the last two bytes in this example are nulled out. And I have no idea why.
The data contains a char object (-2). (`data.write((char) -2));`)

Here is the code on how I wrap up the data into the ByteBuffer:

```
public int send(Connection connection, Packet packet) throws IOException {

    SocketChannel socketChannel = this.socketChannel;
    if(socketChannel == null)
        throw new SocketException("Connection is closed.");

    synchronized (writeLock) {

        writeBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(packet.getDataLength() + 8);
        writeBuffer.order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN);
        
        // checksum
        writeBuffer.putInt(0);
        // packet
        writeBuffer.putChar(packet.getPacketId());
        writeBuffer.putChar(packet.getDataLength());
        writeBuffer.put(packet.getData(), 8, packet.getDataLength());

        // print content of Packet
        System.out.println("SEND [" + String.format("0x%x", (int)packet.getPacketId()) + "] " + BitKit.toString(packet.getRawPacket(), 0, packet.getDataLength() + 8));
        // print content of ByteBuffer
        System.out.println("SEND [" + String.format("0x%x", (int)packet.getPacketId()) + "] " + BitKit.toString(writeBuffer.array(), 0, writeBuffer.array().length));
        
        if(!writeToSocket()) {

            selectionKey.interestOps(SelectionKey.OP_READ | SelectionKey.OP_WRITE);
        } else {
            selectionKey.selector().wakeup();
        }

        lastWriteTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

        return packet.getDataLength();
    }
}
```

The method writeToSocket() just writes the buffer.

```
private boolean writeToSocket() throws IOException {

    SocketChannel socketChannel = this.socketChannel;
    if(socketChannel == null)
        throw new SocketException("Connection is closed.");

    ByteBuffer buffer = writeBuffer;
    buffer.flip();
    while(buffer.hasRemaining()) {

        if(socketChannel.write(buffer) == 0)
            break;
    }
    buffer.compact();

    return buffer.position() == 0;
}
```

I hope you can help me out! Thanks in advance!

Comment: In `writeBuffer.put(packet.getData(), 8, packet.getDataLength());` the `8` is the offset into the `packet.getData()` byte array to start copying from, not the offset into the ByteBuffer to starting writing at. That 3-arg `put()` call is a *relative* put, meaning it starts writing where it last left off. You should probably change the `8` to a `0`.